# Customized BoxShadow in flutter

Tags: flutter, material-design

Is this possible to have a shadow like this =>

[image: Required Resultant]

I have been reading about the [BOXSHADOW](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/painting/BoxShadow-class.html), but do not know how to achieve this. Since the constructors inside the class don't have the required info which I want from this. Maybe the thing I want to achieve is called different in FLUTTER.

**CODE:**

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(
  boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(color: Color.fromRGBO(173, 179, 191, 0.3), blurRadius: 10.0, offset: new Offset(0, 20))] 
)
```

This much I have tried, and want to achieve the aforementioned shadow. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no `shadow` property, there is `boxShadow`.
2. You are using too less opacity. I tested using the color and opacity you added, nothing is visible. Make it 1.0 :)
3. `Offset` expects `double` arguments.
4. You don't need to add `new` keyword in flutter, It doesn't matter but just nice thing to know :)

This works for me -

```
decoration: BoxDecoration(boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(173, 179, 191, 1.0),
                          blurRadius: 10.0,
                          offset: Offset(0.0, -5.0))
                    ]),
```

Comment: The shadow went up. What I want is the shadow should in between the container, like demonstrated in the pic. Also, it should be towards left. Please see the image carefully. Thank for your suggestions, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: I believe shadow is of the size of container and what you are expecting is smaller, Consider using a stack and just keep a container below your container.